# Flash not displaying properly in browsers

Tags: flash, swfobject, fla

I've got a fla player and I'm trying to get it to display inside a div properly, it looks ok in IE (only after you refresh the page), but none of the other browsers show it properly (only 1/4 of the tv shows).. The flash document size is 336px x 220px and I've placed the tv and remote inside.

I'm using SWFObject to call the flash using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var so = new SWFObject("tv.swf?videoUrl=video1.flv&imageUrl=image/image1.jpg&tvName=", "DSI", "100%", "100%", "6", "");
    so.addVariable("autostart","true");
    so.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
    so.write("flashcontent");       
</script>
```

And it sits inside a div which is also 336px x 220px with a red border (for visibility only).

Here's the URL: http://live.gfwa.360southclients.com/commercial/test.html

Can someone help me out with this to get it to display ok, I'm not so good with flash etc.. :S

Oh and here's the action script file:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.media.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class tvplayer extends MovieClip
    {
        private var seekbarChangeInterval:uint;
        private var vid:Video;
        private var mute:Boolean;
        private var imageUrl:String;
        public var remote_mc:MovieClip;
        private var realVideoWidth:Number;
        private var volumeChangeInterval:uint;
        private var videoLoaded:Boolean;
        private var currentState:Boolean;
        private var req:URLRequest;
        private var screenHeight:Number;
        private var screenWidth:Number;
        private var seekbarHideTimer:Timer;
        private var videoUrl:String;
        private var realVideoHeight:Number;
        private var totalVideoTime:Number;
        public var All_mc:MovieClip;
        private var xmlLoader:URLLoader;
        private var muteHideTimer:Timer;
        private var volumeHideTimer:Timer;
        private var videoLoadedInterval:uint;
        private var imageLoader:Loader;
        private var videoLoadedTime:Number;
        private var showVideo:Boolean;
        private var nc:NetConnection;
        private var ns:NetStream;
        private var latestVolumeVal:Number;

        public function tvplayer() : void
        {
            nc = new NetConnection();
            currentState = false;
            screenHeight = 336;
            screenWidth = 580;
            setValues();
            readFlashVars();
            addButtonsEvents();
            arrangeObjects();
            loadImage();
            loadVideo();
            return;
        }// end function

        private function videoFinished() : void
        {
            ns.close();
            vid.clear();
            All_mc.lcd_mc.removeChild(vid);
            All_mc.lcd_mc.imageHolder_mc.alpha = 1;
            remote_mc.playpause_mc.play_mc.visible = true;
            remote_mc.playpause_mc.pause_mc.visible = false;
            clearInterval(videoLoadedInterval);
            videoLoaded = false;
            currentState = false;
            return;
        }// end function

        public function loadImage() : void
        {
            try
            {
                imageLoader = new Loader();
                imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(imageUrl));
                imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, createImage);
            }
            catch (e:Error)
            {
            }
            return;
        }// end function

        private function setValues()
        {
            videoUrl = "video/video1.flv";
            imageUrl = "image/image1.jpg";
            All_mc.txt.text = "Your Logo";
            remote_mc.playpause_mc.pause_mc.visible = false;
            mute = false;
            latestVolumeVal = 1;
            videoLoadedTime = 0;
            All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.volumeBar_mc.width = latestVolumeVal * 348;
            All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            muteHideTimer = new Timer(2000, 1);
            muteHideTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, hideMuteDisplay);
            volumeHideTimer = new Timer(2000, 1);
            volumeHideTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, hideVolumeDisplay);
            seekbarHideTimer = new Timer(2000, 1);
            seekbarHideTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, hideSeekbarDisplay);
            stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fsEvent);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
            remote_mc.ledOn_mc.alpha = 0;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function hideVolumeDisplay(event:TimerEvent) : void
        {
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            volumeHideTimer.stop();
            return;
        }// end function

        private function seekDown_mouseDown(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            muteHideTimer.stop();
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            volumeHideTimer.stop();
            ledon();
            ns.pause();
            seekDown();
            seekbarChangeInterval = setInterval(seekDown, 200);
            return;
        }// end function

        private function metaDataGather(param1:Object) : void
        {
            realVideoHeight = param1.height;
            realVideoWidth = param1.width;
            totalVideoTime = param1.duration;
            setMovieScale();
            return;
        }// end function

        private function seekDown_mouseUp(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            ns.resume();
            if (seekbarChangeInterval)
            {
                clearInterval(seekbarChangeInterval);
            }
            seekbarHideTimer.start();
            ledoff();
            return;
        }// end function

        private function outButton(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            event.currentTarget.out_mc.alpha = 1;
            event.currentTarget.over_mc.alpha = 0;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function updateLoader() : void
        {
            videoLoadedTime = Math.floor(totalVideoTime * (ns.bytesLoaded / ns.bytesTotal));
            return;
        }// end function

        private function stopdrag(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            remote_mc.stopDrag();
            return;
        }// end function

        function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent)
        {
            switch(event.info.code)
            {
                case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
                {
                    trace("Unable to locate video");
                    break;
                }
                case "NetStream.Play.Stop":
                {
                    videoFinished();
                    break;
                }
                case "NetStream.Seek.InvalidTime":
                {
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return;
        }// end function

        private function volumeUp_mouseDown(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            muteHideTimer.stop();
            All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            seekbarHideTimer.stop();
            ledon();
            volumeUp();
            volumeChangeInterval = setInterval(volumeUp, 200);
            return;
        }// end function

        private function arrangeFullscreenObjects() : void
        {
            All_mc.lcd_mc.width = stage.stageWidth;
            All_mc.lcd_mc.height = stage.stageHeight;
            var _loc_1:int = 0;
            All_mc.lcd_mc.y = 0;
            All_mc.lcd_mc.x = _loc_1;
            var _loc_1:int = 0;
            All_mc.y = 0;
            All_mc.x = _loc_1;
            remote_mc.x = All_mc.lcd_mc.x + All_mc.lcd_mc.width - remote_mc.width - 30;
            remote_mc.y = All_mc.lcd_mc.y + All_mc.lcd_mc.height - remote_mc.height - 30;
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.x = Math.floor(All_mc.lcd_mc.x + (All_mc.lcd_mc.width - All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.width) / 2);
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.y = All_mc.lcd_mc.y + (All_mc.lcd_mc.height - All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.height) - 20;
            All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.y = All_mc.lcd_mc.y + (All_mc.lcd_mc.height - All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.height) - 20;
            All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.x = All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.x;
            All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.x = All_mc.lcd_mc.x + (All_mc.lcd_mc.width - All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.width) - 20;
            All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.y = All_mc.lcd_mc.y + 20;
            All_mc.txt.visible = false;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function startdrag(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            remote_mc.startDrag();
            return;
        }// end function

        private function clickPlayPause(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            All_mc.lcd_mc.imageHolder_mc.alpha = 0;
            if (!videoLoaded)
            {
                loadVideo();
            }
            if (currentState)
            {
                currentState = false;
                event.currentTarget.pause_mc.visible = false;
                event.currentTarget.play_mc.visible = true;
                ns.pause();
            }
            else
            {
                currentState = true;
                ns.resume();
                event.currentTarget.play_mc.visible = false;
                event.currentTarget.pause_mc.visible = true;
            }
            return;
        }// end function

        private function addButtonsEvents()
        {
            remote_mc.playpause_mc.buttonMode = true;
            remote_mc.playpause_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickPlayPause);
            remote_mc.playpause_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function ()
            {
                ledon();
                return;
            }// end function
            );
            remote_mc.playpause_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function ()
            {
                ledoff();
                return;
            }// end function
            );
            remote_mc.playpause_mc.play_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overButton);
            remote_mc.playpause_mc.play_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, outButton);
            remote_mc.playpause_mc.pause_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overButton);
            remote_mc.playpause_mc.pause_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, outButton);
            remote_mc.fullscreen_mc.buttonMode = true;
            remote_mc.fullscreen_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickFullscreen);
            remote_mc.fullscreen_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overButton);
            remote_mc.fullscreen_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, outButton);
            remote_mc.fullscreen_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function ()
            {
                ledon();
                return;
            }// end function
            );
            remote_mc.fullscreen_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function ()
            {
                ledoff();
                return;
            }// end function
            );
            remote_mc.remoteBg_mc.buttonMode = true;
            remote_mc.remoteBg_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startdrag);
            remote_mc.remoteBg_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdrag);
            remote_mc.mute_mc.buttonMode = true;
            remote_mc.mute_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleMute);
            remote_mc.mute_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overButton);
            remote_mc.mute_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, outButton);
            remote_mc.mute_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function ()
            {
                ledon();
                return;
            }// end function
            );
            remote_mc.mute_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function ()
            {
                ledoff();
                return;
            }// end function
            );
            remote_mc.volumeUp_mc.buttonMode = true;
            remote_mc.volumeUp_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, volumeUp_mouseDown);
            remote_mc.volumeUp_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, volumeUp_mouseUp);
            remote_mc.volumeUp_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overButton);
            remote_mc.volumeUp_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, outButton);
            remote_mc.volumeDown_mc.buttonMode = true;
            remote_mc.volumeDown_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, volumeDown_mouseDown);
            remote_mc.volumeDown_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, volumeDown_mouseUp);
            remote_mc.volumeDown_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overButton);
            remote_mc.volumeDown_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, outButton);
            remote_mc.forward_mc.buttonMode = true;
            remote_mc.forward_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, seekUp_mouseDown);
            remote_mc.forward_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, seekUp_mouseUp);
            remote_mc.forward_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overButton);
            remote_mc.forward_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, outButton);
            remote_mc.rewind_mc.buttonMode = true;
            remote_mc.rewind_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, seekDown_mouseDown);
            remote_mc.rewind_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, seekDown_mouseUp);
            remote_mc.rewind_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overButton);
            remote_mc.rewind_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, outButton);
            return;
        }// end function

        private function seekUp_mouseDown(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            muteHideTimer.stop();
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            volumeHideTimer.stop();
            ledon();
            seekUp();
            seekbarChangeInterval = setInterval(seekUp, 100);
            return;
        }// end function

        private function volumeDown() : void
        {
            volumeHideTimer.stop();
            if (ns.soundTransform.volume > 0)
            {
                if (ns.soundTransform.volume - 0.1 <= 0)
                {
                    ns.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
                    latestVolumeVal = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    ns.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(ns.soundTransform.volume - 0.1);
                    latestVolumeVal = ns.soundTransform.volume;
                }
            }
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.volumeBar_mc.width = latestVolumeVal * 348;
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.visible = true;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function seekUp_mouseUp(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            if (seekbarChangeInterval)
            {
                clearInterval(seekbarChangeInterval);
            }
            seekbarHideTimer.start();
            ledoff();
            return;
        }// end function

        private function overButton(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            event.currentTarget.over_mc.alpha = 1;
            event.currentTarget.out_mc.alpha = 0;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function ledon() : void
        {
            remote_mc.ledOn_mc.alpha = 1;
            remote_mc.ledOff_mc.alpha = 0;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function seekUp() : void
        {
            if (ns.time < totalVideoTime)
            {
                if (ns.time + 2 >= videoLoadedTime)
                {
                    ns.seek(videoLoadedTime);
                }
                else
                {
                    ns.seek(ns.time + 2);
                }
            }
            All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.seekbar_mc.width = ns.time / totalVideoTime * 348;
            All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.visible = true;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function loadVideo() : void
        {
            videoLoaded = true;
            nc.connect(null);
            ns = new NetStream(nc);
            vid = new Video();
            ns.client = new Object();
            ns.bufferTime = 3;
            ns.play(videoUrl);
            ns.client.onMetaData = metaDataGather;
            ns.pause();
            vid.attachNetStream(ns);
            vid.smoothing = true;
            All_mc.lcd_mc.addChild(vid);
            ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
            ns.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(latestVolumeVal);
            videoLoadedInterval = setInterval(updateLoader, 100);
            return;
        }// end function

        private function volumeUp_mouseUp(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            if (volumeChangeInterval)
            {
                clearInterval(volumeChangeInterval);
            }
            volumeHideTimer.start();
            ledoff();
            return;
        }// end function

        private function seekDown() : void
        {
            if (ns.time > 0)
            {
                if (ns.time - 2 <= 0)
                {
                    ns.seek(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    ns.seek(ns.time - 2);
                }
            }
            All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.seekbar_mc.width = ns.time / totalVideoTime * 348;
            All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.visible = true;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function volumeDown_mouseDown(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            muteHideTimer.stop();
            All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            seekbarHideTimer.stop();
            ledon();
            volumeDown();
            volumeChangeInterval = setInterval(volumeDown, 200);
            return;
        }// end function

        private function readFlashVars()
        {
            var paramObj:Object;
            try
            {
                paramObj = stage.loaderInfo.parameters;
                if (paramObj.videoUrl != null)
                {
                    videoUrl = paramObj.videoUrl;
                }
                if (paramObj.imageUrl != null)
                {
                    imageUrl = paramObj.imageUrl;
                }
                if (paramObj.tvName != null)
                {
                    All_mc.txt.text = paramObj.tvName;
                }
                if (paramObj.screenHeight != null)
                {
                    screenHeight = paramObj.screenHeight;
                }
                if (paramObj.screenWidth != null)
                {
                    screenWidth = paramObj.screenWidth;
                }
            }
            catch (error:Error)
            {
            }
            return;
        }// end function

        private function volumeUp() : void
        {
            if (mute)
            {
                mute = false;
            }
            volumeHideTimer.stop();
            if (ns.soundTransform.volume < 1)
            {
                if (ns.soundTransform.volume + 0.1 >= 1)
                {
                    ns.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
                    latestVolumeVal = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    ns.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(ns.soundTransform.volume + 0.1);
                    latestVolumeVal = ns.soundTransform.volume;
                }
            }
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.volumeBar_mc.width = latestVolumeVal * 348;
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.visible = true;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function clickFullscreen(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL)
            {
                stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
            }
            else
            {
                stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
            }
            return;
        }// end function

        private function ledoff() : void
        {
            remote_mc.ledOn_mc.alpha = 0;
            remote_mc.ledOff_mc.alpha = 1;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function hideSeekbarDisplay(event:TimerEvent) : void
        {
            All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            seekbarHideTimer.stop();
            return;
        }// end function

        private function toggleMute(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            volumeHideTimer.stop();
            if (mute)
            {
                mute = false;
                muteHideTimer.stop();
                All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.muteOn_mc.alpha = 0;
                All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.visible = true;
                ns.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(latestVolumeVal);
                muteHideTimer.start();
            }
            else
            {
                muteHideTimer.stop();
                latestVolumeVal = ns.soundTransform.volume;
                All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.muteOn_mc.alpha = 1;
                All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.visible = true;
                mute = true;
                ns.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
            }
            return;
        }// end function

        private function volumeDown_mouseUp(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            if (volumeChangeInterval)
            {
                clearInterval(volumeChangeInterval);
            }
            volumeHideTimer.start();
            ledoff();
            return;
        }// end function

        private function arrangeObjects()
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            All_mc.x = All_mc.stage.stageWidth / 2 - (screenWidth + 40) / 2;
            All_mc.y = All_mc.stage.stageHeight / 2 - (screenHeight + 55) / 2;
            var _loc_1:int = 20;
            All_mc.lcd_mc.y = 20;
            All_mc.lcd_mc.x = _loc_1;
            All_mc.lcd_mc.scree_bg.width = screenWidth;
            All_mc.lcd_mc.scree_bg.height = screenHeight;
            var _loc_1:int = 0;
            All_mc.tv_bg.y = 0;
            All_mc.tv_bg.x = _loc_1;
            All_mc.tv_bg.width = screenWidth + 40;
            All_mc.tv_bg.height = screenHeight + 55;
            All_mc.foot_mc.y = All_mc.tv_bg.height - 12;
            All_mc.foot_mc.x = Math.floor((All_mc.tv_bg.width - All_mc.foot_mc.width) / 2);
            All_mc.txt.visible = true;
            All_mc.txt.y = All_mc.lcd_mc.y + screenHeight + 5;
            All_mc.txt.x = All_mc.tv_bg.x + Math.floor((All_mc.tv_bg.width - All_mc.txt.textWidth) / 2);
            remote_mc.x = All_mc.x + (screenWidth + 40) - remote_mc.width;
            remote_mc.y = All_mc.y + (screenHeight + 55) - remote_mc.height;
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.x = Math.floor(All_mc.lcd_mc.x + (screenWidth - All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.width) / 2);
            All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.y = All_mc.lcd_mc.y + (screenHeight - All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.height) - 20;
            All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.y = All_mc.lcd_mc.y + (screenHeight - All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.height) - 20;
            All_mc.seekbarDisplay_mc.x = All_mc.volumeDisplay_mc.x;
            All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.x = All_mc.lcd_mc.x + (screenWidth - All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.width) - 20;
            All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.y = All_mc.lcd_mc.y + 20;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function fsEvent(event:FullScreenEvent)
        {
            if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL)
            {
                arrangeObjects();
                All_mc.lcd_mc.width = screenWidth;
                All_mc.lcd_mc.height = screenHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                arrangeFullscreenObjects();
            }
            return;
        }// end function

        private function hideMuteDisplay(event:TimerEvent) : void
        {
            All_mc.muteDisplay_mc.visible = false;
            muteHideTimer.stop();
            return;
        }// end function

        private function createImage(event:Event) : void
        {
            var _loc_2:Bitmap = null;
            _loc_2 = Bitmap(imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.content);
            _loc_2.smoothing = true;
            _loc_2.width = screenWidth;
            _loc_2.height = screenHeight;
            All_mc.lcd_mc.imageHolder_mc.addChild(_loc_2);
            return;
        }// end function

        private function setMovieScale() : void
        {
            if (screenWidth / screenHeight >= realVideoWidth / realVideoHeight)
            {
                vid.height = screenHeight;
                vid.width = realVideoWidth / realVideoHeight * screenHeight;
                vid.x = (screenWidth - vid.width) / 2;
                vid.y = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                vid.width = screenWidth;
                vid.height = realVideoHeight / realVideoWidth * screenWidth;
                vid.y = (screenHeight - vid.height) / 2;
                vid.x = 0;
            }
            return;
        }// end function

        function resizeHandler(event:Event) : void
        {
            All_mc.x = All_mc.stage.stageWidth / 2 - All_mc.width / 2;
            All_mc.y = All_mc.stage.stageHeight / 2 - All_mc.height / 2;
            return;
        }// end function

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to display properly, but now I was wondering if anyone could help me to get the video to play automatically, I've tried

```
        <param name="autoPlay" value="true" />
        <param name="autoStart" value="true" />
```

but they dont work, I'm not sure how to edit the ActionScript to make it play automatically..